# 'Insert Link' link is not pointing to Site Home item

Tags: sxa, multisite, link-manager

We are having multiple SXA sites under a tenant. For all the sites, when we click 'Insert link' on General Link field, able to see Home item of current Site. But, for one site (whose language is de-DE), when we click on 'Insert link', we are getting root item as '/sitecore/content/Home' and the expectation should be Home item of same site. We are using same set of templates for all the sites. I have got the above information in the network tab. Not sure what could be the issue

**For all sites, when we click on 'Insert link', the request is as follows:**

https://my-domain/sitecore/shell/Applications/Dialogs/Internal%20link.aspx?hdl=E6C3B085275C4B5E9C9BA5D0CE569669&ro=&la=en&sc_content

**For one site, when we click on 'Insert link', the request is as follows:**

https://my-domain/sitecore/shell/Applications/Dialogs/Internal%20link.aspx?hdl=3D3BA45EBDEE4080BA0D571F405DFDD3&ro=%2Fsitecore%2Fcontent%2Fhome&la=de-DE&sc_content

Comment: Can you test what happens if you set the language for the site on English? (just as a test) Asking because I have seen strange behavior already on SXA sites with non-English language set as default.

Comment: @Gatogordo, it is working fine if I change site language to en. What should be the next step?

Comment: Open a ticket with Sitecore Support  ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with a patch available [here](https://github.com/SitecoreSupport/Sitecore.Support.293880). Best practice is to contact Sitecore support for advice before applying any patches.